# Regex finding characters across lines

Tags: regex

I have a file with many strings (SQL commands) in it.

```
....
)WITH (
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX ORDER 
(
    [PurchaseOrderTypeID]
)
GO

...
)WITH (
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX ORDER 
(
    [ProgramID],
    [PurchaseOrderTypeID]
)
```

Sometimes there's a list of fields in the Order(), and sometimes there's just 1.
But always, I need to find the occurrence of a literal ] followed by \n followed by the literal )
So that i can ultimately replace it with  ]) \n then )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does the trick ]\n)
just make sure that multi-line is enabled.

Comment: To be safe long term, you should replace `\n` with `\s*` - in this way, you catch any white-space which happens to be there, as well as a missing `\n`.